# Casting from Object to Object[]

Tags: java, arrays, object, casting

I was going though a part of my code, in which I had to **explicitly type-case** different data types into `object` type and vice versa, when I couldn't make sense of how something like this is done :

`(Object[])obj;    //Casting an Object variable into and Object[]`

I have tried to do the same with every other built-in and primitives. It does not work.

`(String[])str;    //Gives the error cannot cast from string to string[]`

`(int[])i;    //Gives the error cannot cast from int to int[]`

`(char[])ch;    //Gives the error cannot cast from char to char[]`

`(long[])l;    //Gives the error cannot cast from long to long[]`

`(Integer[])in;    //Gives the error cannot cast from int to Integer[]`

> where str is a of type `string`, i and in are of type `int`, ch is of
>   type `char`, l is of type `long`.

Then how is it allowed, and internally how is it accomplished when we do
`(Object[])obj;`?

Here `obj` is of type `Object`

Comment: Maybe you don’t get what casting is? Casting doesn’t work unless the object really is an instance of that type.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Any* instance of a refence type is also an Object.

Arrays for example.

An array of String... is an Object.

An array of Object... is an Object.

Therefore, when the actual object is such an array, you can cast back.

But: an array of string is never a string. Therefore that cast does not work!

In code:

```
String[] strings = { "a", "b", "c" };
Object obj = strings;
```

That second line works because *anything* that is "an object", can assigned to an Object variable. And because `obj` is *actually* referencing a string array, you can then cast back:

```
String[] anotherVariablePointingToTheSameArray = (String[]) obj;
```

Keep in mind: that cast has only **one** meaning: *you* know better than the compiler. You know that "something" is actually (at runtime) more specific.

In other words: you can only do a `(X) y` cast if `y instanceOf(X)` would return true!

Comment: I'm sry i still don't get it. Can you please explain a bit more?